# Should a heading be inside or outside a <p>?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a div element and within that div, we have text between p elements.

I want to add a heading. Should it go inside or outside the p?

Which is better:

```
<p>This is text
    <h3>This is my h3</h3>
    More text
</p>
<p>another text<p>
```

or

```
<p>This is text<p>
<h3>This is my h3</h3>
<p>another text<p>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is impossible to put a heading element inside a `p` element in HTML markup, not just formally but because browsers implicitly terminate an open `p` element when they encounter a heading. So the question is meaningless: an element that cannot exist in a certain context cannot have any meaning (semantics) within that context.

Instead of using `p` to group text and headings together, you can use the `div` element or, with the usual caveats, HTML5 novelties like `section` and `article`.

Comment: Okay, you say in a p element only should have text and nothing more,right? Thx!

Comment: There are plenty of things that can go inside paragraphs, but headings aren't one of them.

Answer (score 5):

According to standards a Paragraph should not contain other block elements (including paragraphs and headers). As indicated in other answers, to group a header with a paragraph you can use the div tag.

You can find a lot of information about this subject also on w3c's website: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#block-inline