# How do I get my text div under my image div?

Tags: html, css

I made 3 kinds of div's, 2 on the left side and one on the right side using float. Now I want automatically that my **div text** comes under my **img div** but I cannot get it working with 20 pixels. I have looked around for a bit on stackoverflow but couldn't find the
right answer, also most posts are 2-3 years old. I was wondering if someone could help me out?

[Visit problem](http://jsfiddle.net/FlatDesigner/v8kfc38h/2/)

```
HTML:
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="b1"> </div>
            <div class="b2"> </div>
            <div class="b3"><p><h3>Wildlife</h3><br>Hello fellers how are you doing? In todays project I made something funny ore just not because this is just some random text</p></div>  
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #efede7;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#content{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 962px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.b1 { /*img div*/
    background-color: #34495e;
    height: 290px;
    width: 470px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

.b2 { /*big img div*/
    background-color: blue;
    height: 600px;
    width: 470px;
    float: right;
}

.b3 { /* text div*/
    background-color: #14495e;
    color: #6d6f6f;
    margin: 0;
    height: 290px;
    width: 470px;
    padding: 4% 6% 0;
    font-size: 1.0625em;
    font-family: 'ProximaNova', sans-serif;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #545454;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your question can you refer to the divs by their class so we know what div you want under the other?

Comment: Hello Christopher, I have added it in  the fiddle but I will add it as well in the question.

Comment: use `position:relative;` to b1 , b2  [jsfiddle demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/v8kfc38h/5/)

Comment: In your original question, you specified exact height and width values, is this actually the case in you real-world application? or do you also want a responsive design?

Comment: you have put h3 inside p - that looks weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#content` block has a fixed width and the child elements `.b1`, `.b2`, `.b3` all have specific widths and heights.  This is a perfect layout for absolute positioning.

Try the following:

```css
body {
    background-color: #efede7;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#content{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 962px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative;
}

.b1 { /*img div*/
    background-color: #34495e;
    height: 290px;
    width: 470px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.b2 { /*big img div*/
    background-color: blue;
    height: 600px;
    width: 470px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.b3 { /* text div*/
    background-color: #14495e;
    color: #6d6f6f;
    margin: 0;
    height: 290px;
    width: 470px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.0625em;
    font-family: 'ProximaNova', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 310px;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #545454;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="b1"> </div>
    <div class="b2"> </div>
    <div class="b3"><p><h3>Wildlife</h3><br>Hello fellers how are you doing? In todays project I made something funny ore just not because this is just some random text</p></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">
            <div class="b1"> </div>
            <div class="b3"><p><h3>Wildlife</h3><br>Hello fellers how are you doing? In todays project I made something funny ore just not because this is just some random text</p></div>  
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div class="b2"> </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #efede7;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#content{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 962px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

#left, #right {
    float: left;
}

.b1 { /*img div*/
    background-color: #34495e;
    height: 290px;
    width: 470px;
}

.b2 { /*big img div*/
    background-color: blue;
    height: 600px;
    width: 470px;
}

.b3 { /* text div*/
    background-color: #14495e;
    color: #6d6f6f;
    margin: 0;
    height: 290px;
    width: 471px;
    padding: 4% 6% 0;
    font-size: 1.0625em;
    font-family: 'ProximaNova', sans-serif;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #545454;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Basically I put the two divs you want to appear on the left in a div called `#left` and the one div you want to appear floated next to it in a div called `#right`, and then floated those two divs next to each other. Then the two divs in the `#left` div will naturally appear one under the other.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v8kfc38h/4/

Answer (score 0):

Remove position:absolute from b1 class

Comment: But than will only text go down and not also the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to the following:

```
body {
    background-color: #efede7;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
#content {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 962px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.b1 {
    /*img div*/
    background-color: #34495e;
    height: 290px;
    width: 470px;
    float: left;
    /*position: absolute;  removed, not required*/
}
.b2 {
    /*big img div*/
    background-color: blue;
    height: 600px;
    width: 470px;
    float: right;
}
.b3 {
    /* text div*/
    background-color: #14495e;
    color: #6d6f6f;
    height: 290px;
    width: 355px; /*changed, because padding adds up to form total width of 470px*/
    padding: 4% 6% 0;
    font-size: 1.0625em;
    font-family:'ProximaNova', sans-serif;
    float:left; /*added*/
}
h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #545454;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Working [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yemubolatamu/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me! I found it also just out with a classmate from me =]
Marc Audet did get the closed to the answer thanks for it!

My solution HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="b1"> </div>
        <div class="b2"> </div>
        <div class="b3"><p><h3>Wildlife</h3>
            Hello fellers how are you doing? In todays project I made something funny ore just not because this is just some random text</p>
        </div>
</body>
```

My solution CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #efede7;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#content{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 962px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.b1 {
    background-color: #34495e;
    height: 290px;
    width: 470px;
    float: left;
}

.b2 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 600px;
    width: 470px;
    float: right;
}

.b3 {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6d6f6f;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 430px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.0625em;
    font-family: 'ProximaNova', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #545454;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Greetings,
FlatDesigner

Comment: You cannot put headings inside paragraphs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656785/should-a-heading-be-inside-or-outside-a-p
Apart from that you should consider using HTML5's figcaption for text related to images - http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/