# HTML output is not what I expect it to be

Tags: php

I am having some trouble with php. 
here is my html that I want:

```
<p><h1>name</h1>surname</p>
```

where name and surname is variables in php

what i get is:

```
<p></p> <h1>name</h1> "surname" <p></p>
```

here is my php code:

```
echo "<p> <h1>{$rowsList['Name']}</h1> {$rowsList['Surname']} </p>";
```

Comment: What does $rowsList look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Semantics

The basic semantics:

- **`<h1>`** tag is used for **Headings**.
- **`<p>`** tag is used for **Paragraphs**.

You cannot contain a **Heading** inside a **Paragraph**.

It is not semantically valid and it doesn't make sense. Instead you need to consider removing the surrounding `<p>` tags.

**From other sources:**

*StackOverflow*

> It is impossible to put a heading element inside a `p` element in HTML markup, not just formally but because browsers implicitly terminate an open `p` element when they encounter a heading. So the question is meaningless: an element that cannot exist in a certain context cannot have any meaning (semantics) within that context.
>
> Instead of using `p` to group text and headings together, you can use the `div` element or, with the usual caveats, HTML5 novelties like `section` and `article`.

*W3C*

> According to standards a Paragraph should not contain other block elements (including paragraphs and headers). As indicated in other answers, to group a header with a paragraph you can use the div tag.
>
> You can find a lot of information about this subject also on w3c's website: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#block-inline

#### Solution

Change the PHP Code to:

```
echo "<h1>{$rowsList['Name']}</h1> <p>{$rowsList['Surname']} </p>";
```

#### References:

- [Should a heading be inside or outside a <p>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656785/should-a-heading-be-inside-or-outside-a-p)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with PHP. This is basic HTML.

According to the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html), a `<p>` tag may contain Phrasing Content.

[Phrasing Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content) is defined as:

> Consists of phrasing elements intermixed with normal character data.

[Phrasing Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) are:

> a, em, strong, small, mark, abbr, dfn, i, b, s, u, code, var, samp, kbd, sup, sub, q, cite, span, bdo, bdi, br, wbr, ins, del, img, embed, object, iframe, map, area, script, noscript, ruby, video, audio, input, textarea, select, button, label, output, datalist, keygen, progress, command, canvas, time, meter

Notice how `<h1>` is not among them.

All this to say that the docs explicitly imply (???) that `<p><h1>...</h1></p>` is invalid, and the browser will correct it to its best guess. It should be noted in particular that if you right-click and select View Source (or View Original Source) then you'll see your HTML as you wrote it - it's only in the DOM inspector that you'll see the "corrected" version.