# Why I am not getting change in output when I write the following code in CSS?

Tags: html

Consider the following code :

```
<p align="right"><a href="AddUser.html"><h2>Add 
User</h2></a> |  <a href="AddCustomer.html">Add Customer</a></p>
```

There is not much change in the output when I write the following code in
 the style tag,

```
p {
    font-size  : 7mm;
        font-family: Garamond;
        font-style : Normal;
}
```

But if I write the same code in h2{}  or a{} the echange is quite visible.
Kindly explain why is it so ?

Comment: Is that the *only* CSS code you have?

Comment: Look at your browser's element inspector. Any decent modern browser will tell you exactly which CSS rule overrides which on any given element.

Comment: Yes if I change font-size there is no significant change in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using *block level elements* (the `<h2>` in this case) inside a paragraph, which is not possible.

From the [W3C reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1):

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

So most web browsers will actually break your paragraph and then, since the rest of the content is outside it, it will not apply the CSS style.

If you check it with the developer tools (in Chrome, for example), you'll see that the `<h2>` tag is actually **outside** of the paragraph.

Demo:
[image]

The bottom line, and general recommendation is: do not use paragraphs as "html blocks", or headers for styling inline elements... use the recommended `<div>` and `<span>` tags for it.

HTML should be **semantic**, and what you are writing there is neither a paragraph, nor a header. Use the right tags

Comment: But even "Add Customer" which is outside <h2> is not displaying the change

Comment: @user4449595 since the browser is breaking the first paragraph, the rest of it is implementation dependent... if you check the output in the developer console (check my screenshot), the other link is outside any block level element (it's directly a child of `<body>`, so it's not inside any `<p></p>` either (and thus, not styled). The `<p></p>` you see at the end is the browser's best guess to comply with your closing `</p>` tag, but it doesn't have content inside it.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `header` tags are not supposed to be inside `paragraph`. As the name suggests, its meant for headers.

Use `<span>` instead of `<h2>` if you want to make any changes. If you remove the `<h2>` in above code, the css will work fine.

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8s4y2vy1/)

You can use `<span>` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fx3mmL4n/)

Also, read this : [Should a heading be inside or outside a <p>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656785/should-a-heading-be-inside-or-outside-a-p)

Comment: But even "Add Customer" which is outside <h2> is not displaying the change