# Difference result for a heading within p and div tag

Tags: html, css, paragraph, heading

I was trying to make a paragraph for an email address. But I cannot make style for it.

```css
.mail a {
    margin: .7rem 0;
    padding: .3em .8em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    transition: all .2s;
    color: #aaa;
}

    .mail a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }


    .mail a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }
```

```html
<p class="mail"><h3><a href="mailto:chenghuayang.com@gmail.com">chenghuayang.com@gmail.com</a></h3></p>
  <hr>
<div class="mail"><h3><a href="mailto:chenghuayang.com@gmail.com">chenghuayang.com@gmail.com</a></h3></div>
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xufuze/edit?html,css,output) is here.

I've never realised there's some more difference between `p` and `div` other than semantic meaning or properties like `margin` or `line-height`.

Okay, I'll use `div` instead of `p` tag. But here are the questions in my mind:

1. What do you call this difference, and why does it work like this?
2. Are there any other examples of this behaviour? (I hope I wouldn't miss anything else like this.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with how a `div` and a `p` tag work. It has to do with the fact that you have an heading (`h3`) inside a `p` tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656785/should-a-heading-be-inside-or-outside-a-p

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that. Not quite familiar with general layout practice.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida Is there any article about the practice of formal layout? I'd like to know more about it, so that won't miss anything important.

Comment: @ChenghuaYang I've added a bit more info to my answer regarding other elements that can be self closed. Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is occurring because the `h3` element cannot belong inside a `p` element. The end tag of a `p` element can be omitted if it is followed by certain elements:

> **Tag omission**
>
> The start tag is mandatory. The end tag may be omitted if the `<p>` element is immediately followed by an `<address>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<blockquote>`, `<div>`, `<dl>`, `<fieldset>`, `<footer>`, `<form>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`, `<header>`, `<hr>`, `<menu>`, `<nav>`, `<ol>`, `<pre>`, `<section>`, `<table>`, `<ul>` or another `<p>` element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an `<a>` element.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

Effectively, your `p` tags are closing before the `h3` tags are opened so this:

```
<p class="mail"><h3><a href="mailto:chenghuayang.com@gmail.com">chenghuayang.com@gmail.com</a></h3></p>
```

Actually becomes this:

```
<p class="mail"></p>
<h3><a href="mailto:chenghuayang.com@gmail.com">chenghuayang.com@gmail.com</a></h3>
```

As a result your `.mail a` rule no longer applies to the `a` tag which causes it to be un-styled.

To fix, simply remove the `p` tags and add the `mail` class to the `h3`:

```css
.mail a {
  margin: .7rem 0;
  padding: .3em .8em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: all .2s;
  color: #aaa;
}
.mail a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.mail a:hover {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="mail"><a href="mailto:chenghuayang.com@gmail.com">chenghuayang.com@gmail.com</a></h3>
<hr>
<div class="mail">
  <h3><a href="mailto:chenghuayang.com@gmail.com">chenghuayang.com@gmail.com</a></h3>
</div>
```

There are other tags where the end tag is optional (shown below), however, the rules as to when they are automatically closed differ:

```
</HTML>
</HEAD>
</BODY>
</P>
</DT>
</DD>
</LI>
</OPTION>
</THEAD>
</TH>
</TBODY>
</TR>
</TD>
</TFOOT>
</COLGROUP>
```

([HTML: Include, or exclude, optional closing tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags))

For example, `li` will autoclose if a new `li` is opened:

> **Tag omission**
>
> The end tag can be omitted if the list item is immediately followed by another `<li>` element, or if there is no more content in its parent element.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

While `td`s will close automatically if followed by a `th` or `td`:

> **Tag omission**
>
> The start tag is mandatory. The end tag may be omitted, if it is
>   immediately followed by a `<th>` or `<td>` element or if there are no more
>   data in its parent element.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)

A useful list of the elements and whether they need to be closed can be found on the W3C site: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/elements.html

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the way both tags work.

It has to do with the fact you have an `h3` inside the `p`. Why?

> It is impossible to put a heading element inside a p element in HTML
>   markup, not just formally but because browsers implicitly terminate an
>   open p element when they encounter a heading.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656785/should-a-heading-be-inside-or-outside-a-p)

Working sample with `p` tag without `h3`:

```css
.mail a {
    margin: .7rem 0;
    padding: .3em .8em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    transition: all .2s;
    color: #aaa;
}

    .mail a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }


    .mail a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }
```

```html
<p class="mail"><a href="mailto:chenghuayang.com@gmail.com">chenghuayang.com@gmail.com</a></p>
  <hr>
<div class="mail"><h3><a href="mailto:chenghuayang.com@gmail.com">chenghuayang.com@gmail.com</a></h3></div>
```