# Can a paragraph be a parent-element?

Tags: javascript, html

Should mention:
I'm not the most experienced web-coder.
Nevertheless: Currently dealing with some frontend stuff.

Yesterday I programmed some JavaScript and the results wasn't as I had expected.

I made this demo:

Every paragraph contains a headline and some text. The paragraphs are enclosed within a div-container.

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="paragraph">
    <h3 class="headline">Some headline ...</h3>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. </span>
  </p>

  <p class="paragraph">
    <h3 class="headline">Another headline ...</h3>
    <span>Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.</span>
  </p>

  <!-- More paragraph-container ... -->
</div>
```

Let's say I have a reference to the first headline and would like to get the class-name of the first paragraph-tag.

I would to something like this:

```
// Get a reference to the first headline element.
var headline = document.getElementsByClassName('headline')[0];
// Access the parent of the headline element.
console.log(headline.parentNode.className);
// Result is: container
```

I expect as return 'paragraph' because the paragraph encloses the headline. Instead I get the class-name of the div.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: You got it wrong, `parentNode` returns the first parent element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `container` instead of `paragraph` because the web-browser is *correcting* your malformed html code structure:

[image]

The error is that `<p>` element should contain a text body and not other elements.

Changing your `<p>` tag to `<div>` makes your code work perfectly like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <h3 class="headline">Some headline ...</h3>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. </span>
  </div>

  <div class="paragraph">
    <h3 class="headline">Another headline ...</h3>
    <span>Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not valid html to put heading elements (`<h1>`, `<h2>` etc.) inside paragraph elements.

Your browser is probably closing the paragraph element before the `<h3>` element, therefore the parent of `<h3>` becomes your `container` `<div>`,

Answer (score 0):

"I expect as return 'paragraph' because the paragraph encloses the headline. Instead I get the class-name of the div."

Because both `<p>` and `<h3>` are block elements. They are not placed inside each other. Just like you cannot add `<div>` or `<p>` inside `<table>` or `<tr>`.

to make `<h3>` inline you have to set css `display: inline`.

refer: [Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

Comment: Aren't `<p>` and `<h3>` inline elements?

Comment: @choz Not if they aren't set by CSS

Comment: yes to make them inline you have to set css "display: inline"

Comment: @aspirin Just wondering if I get this methodology right. `<span>` is an inline element, isn't it?

Comment: @choz unless you set `display:block` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have invalid html.
You should not put H3 inside the paragraph, but above it.
Browsers will select the `<div>` as parent, not the `<p>` element

[Read this article: Should a heading be inside or outside a `<p>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656785/should-a-heading-be-inside-or-outside-a-p)