# Template Parse errors in angular2 template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template

I have the following template for my angular 2 component, but it is throwing a template parse error.

```
<div *ngIf="chapter == 1">
        <p><h4><br><b>Exercise</b>: Get the Groceries starting point<br></h4></p>
</div>
```

this is the error message - what's wrong with my `</p>` tag?

> zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Unexpected closing tag "p" ("gIf="chapter == 1">
>
> ```
>    <p><h4><br><b>Exercise</b>: Get the Groceries starting point<br></h4>
> ```
>
> [ERROR ->]
>
> ```
> </div>
> ```
>
> "): chapterComponent@45:77 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException {message: "Template parse errors:↵Unexpected closing tag "p" …ROR ->]
>
> ↵
>   ↵
>   ↵"): chapterComponent@45:77", stack: "Error: Template parse errors:↵Unexpected closing t…st:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22)"}consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>   zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:(…)consoleError @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426

Comment: maybe use `<br />` instead of `<br>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that header `h4` in your paragraph!
Its no valid HTML code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15656988/3631348

Do it without that `p` ?! Or move the header right before your paragraph..

```
<h4><br><b>Exercise</b>: Get the Groceries starting point<br></h4>
```