# How do I remove space between the divs?

Tags: html, css

I have two `<div>` sections, one with content on top and the other with image below. I want the `<div>` to seat on top of other that is I would like to erase the space between the two `<div>`s. How do I do it?

```css
.boxed-green {
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
  border: none;
  background: #5AAD97;
}

.boxed-green h3 {
  padding: 4% 6% 3% 6%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  font-family: "Verdana", "Times New Roman";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: black;
}

.boxed-green h4 {
  padding: 0% 6% 8% 6%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Verdana", "Times New Roman";
  color: black;
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="boxed-green">
      <p>
        <h3> Who We Are </h3>
      </p>
      <p>
        <h4>Test Test Test Test Test Test</h4>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="images\vivid_studios\studio1_1.png" alt="Picture1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`H4` does have default margin applied by the browser, so you have to make it to 0.

There are few bugs in your code:

Don't use heading tag inside `p` tag as it will terminate `p` tag ( [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656785/should-a-heading-be-inside-or-outside-a-p) ).

Try using [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalise](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) css. As this will not allow browsers to apply their default styles.

```css
.col-md-3 > div{
line-height:0;
}
.boxed-green {
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
  border: none;
  background:#5AAD97;
}

.boxed-green h3 {
  padding :4% 6% 3% 6%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  font-family: "Verdana", "Times New Roman";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
  color:black;
}

.boxed-green h4 {
  padding :0% 6% 8% 6%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Verdana", "Times New Roman";
  color:black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
 }

 img {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="boxed-green">
  <h3> Who We Are </h3>
  <h4>Test Test Test Test Test Test</h4>
 </div>
 <div>
 <img src="images\vivid_studios\studio1_1.png" alt="Picture1">
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Afsar for the info on p tags. I removed the <p> tags and its working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps: `div{line-height:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

Update .boxed-green to following

```
     .boxed-green {
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
  border: none;
  background:#5AAD97;
  line-height:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/jpewas4f/ . Add `margin-bottom:0px;` to class ".boxed-green h4", like following:

```
.boxed-green h4 {
  padding :0% 6% 8% 6%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Verdana", "Times New Roman";
  color:black;
  margin-bottom:0px;
 }
```

Comment: Have u used the same html, in your code <h3> & <h4> tag comes inside <p> tag, & when i run the html it shows error, so i put <p> tag inside <h3> & <h4>. Then it worked. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Provide `margin: 0` to your `p` elements. By default `p` elements take native margin properties as defined by the browser.

And also, give `margin-bottom: 0` to your `.boxed-green h4`.

Refer code:

```css
.boxed-green {
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
  border: none;
  background: #5AAD97;
}

.boxed-green h3 {
  padding: 4% 6% 3% 6%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  font-family: "Verdana", "Times New Roman";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: black;
}

.boxed-green h4 {
  padding: 0% 6% 8% 6%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Verdana", "Times New Roman";
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="boxed-green">
      <p>
        <h3> Who We Are </h3>
      </p>
      <p>
        <h4>Test Test Test Test Test Test</h4>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYxMjk0NDg4Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODcyNjA5OTE@._V1._SX600_SY600_.jpg" alt="Picture1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply but still its not working for me. I changed the image too to see if its working but its not.

Comment: Check the code snipped I added here, and look at the result. It should work and is clearly working

Comment: You are supposed to upvote or mark the answer as correct if it did help you. Appreciate people's efforts here. ;)