# Very unintuitive "Unexpected closing tag" error on a valid template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6, angular7

It's my first day of learning angular and I've encountered a very unintuitive error message, which says:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "p". It
>   may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For
>   more info see
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
>         Number {{ i + 1 }}: {{ phoneNumber }}    [ERROR ->]
>
> "): ng:///AppModule/AddressCardComponent.html@5:0

The error is thrown on a valid html template that looks like this:

```
<p>Phones:</p>
<p *ngFor="let phoneNumber of user.phone; index as i">
  <h3>
      Number {{ i + 1 }}: {{ phoneNumber }}
  </h3>
</p>
```

and in the component itself it just looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-card',
  templateUrl: './address-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address-card.component.scss']
})
export class AddressCardComponent implements OnInit {

  user: any;

  constructor() {
    this.user = {
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      title: 'Software Developer',
      address: '1234 Main St., State, City 610010',
      phone: [
        '123-123-1234',
        '456-546-4574'
      ]
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The cool thing is that if I change the inner `h3` tag to a `span` or `a`, it works perfectly as expected, whereas when the inner tag is `p`, `h3`, `h2`, `h1`, `div` etc it just breaks with the same error.

It seams it just doesn't like certain kinds of tags, lol

---

Anyway,

1. Am I doing something wrong here? If so, how should I correct the template? What do I miss?
2. Are there many situations when that much unintuitive error messages come up while developing angular apps?

---

PS: I'm using Angular v7.0.5 if it makes any difference

Comment: Take a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656785/should-a-heading-be-inside-or-outside-a-p). You cannot have an `h1` tag inside a `p` tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a heading be inside or outside a <p>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656785/should-a-heading-be-inside-or-outside-a-p)

Comment: @user184994 Well, the browsers do render such things even though it doesn't follow the standards. Another question then: does angular really need to tell me what tags to use? and moreover, with such vague error messages...  Feels a bit weird

Comment: I'd argue that it isn't that vague. It tells you exactly which tag is causing the error, and a link to the w3 spec that shows you the reason. The browser will automatically insert a closing `p` tag as soon as it reaches your `h1`, so you now have the original closing tag without a matching opening tag

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you, guys, this topic was new to me. I think I should take some time with angular to get more used to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For HTML 5 to validate, heading tags cannot be inside paragraph tags. I suspect your code will also run fine if you replace `<p *ngFor="let phoneNumber of user.phone; index as i">` with `<div *ngFor="let phoneNumber of user.phone; index as i">`

I am finding that Angular will often really force you to do things correctly. The way they see it, there is a standard, and it's there for a reason. So even if technically the code runs, there are potential side-effects that will happen elsewhere. And those, those might be a total PITA to find. So, they force you on the right path at the very core. This is probably a big part of the reason that Angular has a steep learning curve. It questions everything you think you already know.

Some Angular error messages can be a bit... vague. But I think I've struggled with JS errors just as much at the start.

Comment: Well, yeah, you're right. But it still feels a bit weird that angular tells me what tags to use and where to use them. At least, they shoud've come up with an appropriate error message...

Comment: I've updated my answer to better address the full set of your questions. :)

Comment: You can replace too by < ng-container *ngFor="...>< p>..< /p>< /ng-container>