# Why do I not see HTML <h3> tags in console output when using innerHTML or innerText?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

[image]

```js
consoleOutputText = document.getElementById('phrase2').innerText
consoleOutputHTML = document.getElementById('phrase2').innerHTML

console.log(consoleOutputText)
console.log(consoleOutputHTML)
```

```html
<p id='phrase2'>This **[<h3>statement</h3>][1]** <b>populates</b> in browser Console.</p>
```

Comment: You cannot nest an `<h3>` within a `<p>`.

Comment: Related: [Should a heading be inside or outside a `<p>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15656785/4642212)

Answer (score 1):

- `<h3>` cannot be a descendant of `<p>`.
- So your HTML is incorrect.
- So your browser changes the structure of the document [as per HTML5's rules for fixing broken, malformed and incorrect documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser):
- So the browser takes out the `<h3>` and splits the `<p>` in-two.
- So your actual document structure changes...

  - ...from this (each DOM node, including `#text` nodes,, is on its own line):

    ```
    <p id='phrase2'>
    This **[
    <h3>statement</h3>
    ][1]**
    <b>populates</b>
    in browser Console.
    </p>
    ```
  - to this (each DOM node, including `#text` nodes, is on its own line):

    ```
    <p id='phrase2'>This **[</p>
    <h3>statement</h3>
    "][1]**
    <b>populates</b> in browser Console.
    <p></p>
    ```
- Because the `<h3>` element is styled as a block-level element by default it causes the line-break inside the rendered page.
- Also, don't use `innerText`, use `textContent` instead.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Correct - thank you for correcting me, I'll update my answer now.