# Why descendant selector in CSS3 doesn't work with h1?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I used descendant selector and I declared the style process in the head section

In the HTML head:

```html
<style>
  p h1 {
    color: blue;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

In the HTML body:

```
<p>
  <h1>
    I am Anik Islam
  </h1>
</p>
```

It didn't show blue colored letters and red colored background, it showed the default instead. What am I missing here?

Comment: css code please?

Comment: `h1` tag inside `p` is wrong format.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15656988/11350283

Comment: @Manjuboyz how?

Comment: @ashishsingh I provided it

Comment: @devcrp thanks for trying to help me,but it's still not clear.I don't find the relevence

Comment: You can't put `h1` inside a `p` element

Comment: `is impossible to put a heading element inside a p element in HTML markup, not just formally but because browsers implicitly terminate an open p element when they encounter a heading` hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is **malformed**.

You can not place an `h` element inside a `p` element. Header tags should be separate block elements not nested within paragraph elements.

In addition, many web browsers will auto-close open `<p>` tags if another block element is encountered such as `<h1>`.

Chances are very high the *browser* is rendering your markup as...

```
<p>

</p>

<h1>
 I am Anik Islam
</h1>

</p>
```

Therefore there is *no nesting* taking place. So, consequently the CSS isn't seeing any nesting.

If you wish to nest elements, use `div` tags. or if you wish to style the `h1` specifically, target it by adding a class or ID to it.

Comment: "*many web browsers...*", they should all do this, it's part of [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/tokenization.html#parsing-main-inbody) "***A start tag whose tag name is one of: "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"** If the stack of open elements has a p element in button scope, then act as if an end tag with the tag name "p" had been seen*"

Comment: Agreed, but I can't be absolutely definitive unless I check *every possible* web browser `:)`